# Why is case 2 printing when I enter 2?

Tags: java, switch-statement, tostring

I am working on a program that tracks items and their costs as you add them to you bag. I have switch statement to give options for 1.  adding new items, 2. printing the totals, and 3. ending the program.

For some reason when I select case 1 it also prints the totals using my toString method. But I only have the toString method in case 2.

Can anyone explain why this would be happening?

Here is my main

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ShoppingBagTracker {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        float taxRate, cost;
        int items, newItems, choice;
        String receipt;
        String menu = ("1. Add items" +
        "2. Get receipt"
        + "3. Exit");

        System.out.print("Enter the sales tax rate: ");
        taxRate = in.nextFloat();
        ShoppingBag myBag = new ShoppingBag(taxRate);

        items = 0;
        do{
            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println(menu);
            choice = in.nextInt();

            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Enter cost of item: ");
                    cost = in.nextFloat();     

                    System.out.print("Enter number of items: ");
                    newItems = in.nextInt();
                    items = items + newItems;

                    myBag.place(items, cost);
                    myBag.getItems();
                    myBag.getCost();
                    myBag.getTotal();
                    myBag.getAverage();
                case 2:
                   receipt = myBag.toString();
                   System.out.println(receipt);
                case 3:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("That is not an option");      
            }
        }while(choice != 3);            
    }    
}
```

Here is my Shopping Bag class

```
public class ShoppingBag {

    public float taxRate;
    public int items;
    public float cost;
    public float average;
    public float totalCost;
    public float finalCost;

    public ShoppingBag(float taxRate)
    {
        this.taxRate = taxRate;
    }

    public void place(int newitems, float newcost)
    {
        items = newitems;
        cost = newcost;

        cost = items * cost;
    }

    public int getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }

    public float getCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }

    public float getTotal()
    {
        finalCost = cost + (cost * taxRate);
        return finalCost;
    }

    public float getAverage()
    {
        average = finalCost/items;
        return average;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return("Items: " + items + " Cost: " + cost + " Total cost: " + finalCost + " Average cost: " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add break in the end of your case switch

Comment: You do not have `break`, so it falls down into `Case 2`.

Comment: I'll give an up-vote to anybody who mentions adding `break` to each case AND `Scanner#nextLine` ... and knows why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A switch case isn't restrict to execute one 'case'. It execute all code from the matching case down to a `break;` or to the end of the switch.

In your case add a `break;` before the case 2

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `break` in `switch-cases`.

```
switch(something){
     case 1:
     // do something
     break;
     case 2:
     //do something
     break;
     default:
     // do something
     break;      

}
```

If there is no `break`, that will execute all cases here.

[switch-cases](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) in `Java`.

Conclusion.

If there is no `return` in cases, you should use `break` for every case.

Following case you don't need `break`.

```
   switch (cases){
        case "a":
            return "a";
        case "b":
            return "b";
        default:
            return "default";
    }
```

Comment: It's not *just* `return` that's an exception, but every flow-control statement that exits the `switch`. Still, for beginners it's probably better to be overzealous with `break`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a break statement inside the case 1 body

```
                case 1:
                System.out.print("Enter cost of item: ");
                cost = in.nextFloat();     

                System.out.print("Enter number of items: ");
                newItems = in.nextInt();
                items = items + newItems;

                myBag.place(items, cost);
                myBag.getItems();
                myBag.getCost();
                myBag.getTotal();
                myBag.getAverage();
                break;
```

Here is the official [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should either have a break for all the cases or have a return statements in all cases. Otherwise when Java will execute all the cases which are after the matching case.

```
swicth(urSwitch){
   case 1:// logic
      break; // or return something
   case 2:// logic
      break; // or return something
   case 3:// logic
      break; // or return something
}
```